# Pandas group from group.keys throws KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

Im trying to group my Pandas DataFrame with all possible grouping combinations. My code looks like this:

```py
 df_grouped = input_df.groupby(condition)
 for group_key in df_grouped.groups.keys():
    newly_grouped_df = df_grouped.get_group(group_key)
```

You see that I iterate over every group that I got through the '.keys()'.
The thing is that this approach works on my artificially created training data set just fine. But when I use it on real data this last line throws a

```
KeyError: (35691, 'B1234', 'red', 'DFOIJFSDOIJF (36)', nan, 'street', '0,59', 'Incorrect')
```

How is that possible? The key comes from the dataFrame itself but then throws a keyerror?

Comment: Is it possilbe for you to create a small subset of data that reproduces this error.  Or give access to the data if not to big so we can generate this error?

Comment: Probably is because you have a __nan__ value as part of your key. Try using `.fillna()` to replace the nan values with other thing.

Comment: Thanks, the fillna() was doing it for me